# Approach to minimize dir-hardcoding in a RewriteRule that works from root and subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, subdirectory

I have this project that I locally run from the root of a webserver. It's a schoolproject so it will be deployed to my school's servers which require me to put it inside a subfolder. This is causing troubles with the static+css redirects because it clearly doesn't work the way it is written now when run from a subfolder, and I don't want to hardcode every rewrite-rule to the subfolder because that's is ugly, and makes it hard to switch to using running it from root if I need that.

The project has the following rules in a .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /static/
RewriteRule ^static/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /css/
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ static/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Is there an approach that lets me get the above rewrites to work from both root and a subfolder no questions asked, or a way that makes the difference minimal? (where I don't need to hardcode the subfolder in every rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way I see it (assuming the .haccess is also in the subfolder)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#you might need a rewritebase, but not necessarily 
#testing
#RewriteBase /
#production
#RewriteBase /subfolder

#less strict condition. will only be a problem if there is another folder also named 'static' inside 'static' :-)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /static/
RewriteRule ^static/(.*) $1 [L,R=301]

#condition here is not needed
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ static/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, and even better: if I omit a RewriteBase, it works both if i deploy to root or to a subfolder all by itself! Thank you very much for the solution.